# workaround for tinymce utf8 bug

Tags: php, tinymce

Background: I have a web site that uses tinymce to edit HTML. HTML entities like non-breaking space and &x22C4; are getting converted to UTF-8 characters by tinymce, even though I am using the entity_encoding:"named" option.  I then store it in a MySQL table that is UTF-8.  When the same HTML is retrieved later for re-editing, the multi-byte characters are separated into individual characters by tinymce.  Tinymce has verified this is a bug.

The question is: how do I convert all the multi-byte UTF-8 characters into HTML entities without breaking the HTML?

I tried the following in PHP, but the multi-byte UTF-8 characters are just removed:

```
$encoded_string = htmlentities( $utf_string, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8', false );
$html_ent_conv = htmlspecialchars_decode ( $encoded_string , ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5 );
```

I also tried mb_encode_numericentity, but I couldn't figure out what I should use for the convmap parameter.

Update: I have PHP 5.3.17, which doesn't support ENT_HTML5, so I removed it.  Now it works for non-breaking space, but not for other multi-byte UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, I ran into this piece of code in the PHP documentation:

```
function utf8_to_html($data)
{
  return preg_replace("/([\\xC0-\\xF7]{1,1}[\\x80-\\xBF]+)/e", '_utf8_to_html("\\1")', $data);
}

function _utf8_to_html($data)
{
  $ret = 0;

  foreach((str_split(strrev(chr((ord($data{0}) % 252 % 248 % 240 % 224 % 192) + 128) . substr($data, 1)))) as $k => $v)
    $ret += (ord($v) % 128) * pow(64, $k);

  return "&#$ret;";
}
```

Went out and found it again:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Brilliant little snippet that's saved my bacon on a couple of occasions.